# Handshake Failure: SSL Alert number 40

Tags: ssl, curl, web-scraping, openssl, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a page without success:

```
>> scrapy shell "XXXXXX"
...
2018-12-28 17:23:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET XXXXXXXX> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]>]
2018-12-28 17:23:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET XXXXXXXXXXXXX> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]>]
2018-12-28 17:23:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 73, in run
    shell.start(url=url, redirect=not opts.no_redirect)
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 48, in start
    self.fetch(url, spider, redirect=redirect)
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 115, in fetch
    reactor, self._schedule, request, spider)
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
    result.raiseException()
  File "/home/joaquin/Repos/extruct/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 467, in raiseException
    raise self.value.with_traceback(self.tb)
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]>]
```

when try a SSL connection I got:

```
>> openssl s_client XXXXX.XXXX.XXXX:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140087350686208:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1528:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 323 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Also when I try this page with `curl` happens the same:

```
curl -i XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I try to specify `-servername` in `openssl` but it doesn't fix the problem. Also trying to specify `-tls1_2` doesn't work. TLS Info:

[image: TLS INFO]

### UPDATE

```
>> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018
```

Comment: As written RSA/3DES_EDE_CBC/HMAC-SHA1 are obsolete and while your browser may be lenient enough to accept them, your openssl version does not seem to be. You will need at least to tell about your openssl version, and if you do `openssl ciphers` you will see if you have `3DES-EDE-CBC` or not. Alternatively try online scanners like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: I updated my question, its OpenSSL 1.1.1a

Comment: OpenSSL since 1.1.0 no longer includes _or_ enables 'weak' ciphersuites, defined as 3DES and RC4, by default; _if_ your build was done with 'enable-weak-ssl-ciphers' `s_client ... -cipher DES-CBC3-SHA` should work. @PatrickMevzek+ when they are supported, for most 3DES suites OpenSSL uses a 'swapped' name with the 3 at the right: DES-CBC3-SHA ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA etc.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 FWIW indeed my `openssl ciphers` still show some names with a 3 as prefix, such as `PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: which is why I used 'most'

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I tried to compile with that option but it doesn't work at all, I used this: ```./Configure --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/etc/ssl --libdir=lib \
  shared enable-ssl3 enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3-method enable-weak-ssl-ciphers linux-x86_64 \```, after install, I run this command and returns empty output: 
`openssl ciphers | grep -i "3DES"`, also when i try to connect  `openssl s_client XXXXX.XXXX.XXXX:443` it doesn't work

Comment: It might sound obvious, but… have you tried using HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found your question while searching for the exact same problem (`curl` succeeds to connect while `openssl` fails with `alert number 40`).

It might be related to a server with several virtual hosts to serve, and you need to tell which host you want to connect to, to let the TLS handshake succeed.

Specify the exact host name you want with `-servername` parameter. E.g:

```
openssl s_client -connect yourserver.domain.com:443 -servername yourserver.domain.com
```