# Spring boot(Tomcat) ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH on MacOS only

Tags: java, spring-boot, macos, ssl, tomcat

I have a problem that only happened on macOS(linux and windows works fine),

we are using tomcat server via spring web, the only ssl related configuration is:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-password: password
    key-password: password
    key-store: <path to jks>
    key-alias: alias
    enabled: true
```

when trying to access the server via chrome we get:

`ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

when trying to call via postman we also get the following:

[image]

spring boot version is 2.6.3,

any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handshake Failure: SSL Alert number 40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965049/handshake-failure-ssl-alert-number-40)

Comment: @pringi didn't help, must be another issue with mac & localhost