# SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

This is the error message I encountered after executing the code:

```
BIO_do_connect error.
139779664143680:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
```

OpenSSL version:

```bash
root@V:~# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

This is my test code. If you use this code to connect to other servers, such as YouTube, Google, Twitter, Stackoverflow, etc., there will be no problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/sslerr.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

#if defined(__linux)
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")
#endif

#define HOSTNAME "www.pixiv.net"
static const char* sendbuf = (
    "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: "HOSTNAME"\r\n"
    "Accept: */*\r\n"
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0\r\n\r\n"
);

void openssl_bio_test()
{
    SSL_CTX *ssl_ctx = NULL;
    BIO *bio = NULL;
    SSL *ssl = NULL;
    char recvbuf[4096];

    ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ssl_ctx);

    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, HOSTNAME":443");

    if (BIO_do_connect(bio) != 1) {
        printf("BIO_do_connect error.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        return;
    }

    memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));
    BIO_write(bio, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf));
    BIO_read(bio, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf));

    fwrite(recvbuf, 1, strlen(recvbuf), stdout);

    BIO_free_all(bio);
    SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    openssl_bio_test();
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, my previous Python programming problem was similar to this, and I found a solution at that time.

At that time, I learned the solution to the problem with Python by browsing its official documentation. `ssl.wrap_socket` was already deprecated in `Python v3.7` because it seemed to be due to insufficient functionality or some other issue.

The code is as follows:

Error code for demonstration:

```py
import socket
import ssl

sockfd = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket())
sockfd.connect(('www.pixiv.net', 443))
sockfd.close()

'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/py398/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1342, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/root/py398/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1333, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/root/py398/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)
'''
```

#### Correct code for demonstration:

```py
import socket
import ssl

sockfd = ssl.SSLContext().wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname='www.pixiv.net')
sockfd.connect(('www.pixiv.net', 443))
sockfd.close()

'''
No errors will occur.
'''
```

And in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965049/handshake-failure-ssl-alert-number-40), it was also mentioned that the error was caused by not specifying 'server_hostname'. Therefore, I suspect that this may be the reason for the code problem. If so, I am a bit unsure how to solve this problem in C code.

Comment: In short: no SNI used for a site which requires SNI. You'll find the necessary function to set SNI in the answer to the duplicated question